# Android: Accessing Widget from Event Listener

Tags: android, events

In my Android application, I have an ImageView (in the onCreate method) with an onTouch listener attached like so:

```
    ball.setClickable(true);
    ball.setOnTouchListener(ballDragListener);
```

and the event listener:

```
View.OnTouchListener ballDragListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.pet_layout); // Reference to the already created layout
        int velocityX = 1;
        int velocityY = 1;

        int eventAction = event.getAction();
        int newX = (int)(event.getRawX());
        int newY = (int)(event.getRawY());

        v.setX(newX + velocityX);
        v.setY(newY + velocityY);
        //v.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

Say I declare a new TextView in the onCreate method:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
```

How would I access it from the event listener? Calling 'text.setText()' doesn't work, as it cannot find the object.

**Edit: I would also like to be able to access the same instance of the TextView from my onCreate() method, and/or another method.**

Regards,
Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1)

Declare your textview as a field in your class like:

```
private TextView text;
```

And then just init it as you did now but without declaring it (you already did in your class as a field):

```
text = new TextView(this);
```

2)

Or just add a final modifier to it and do this a few lines before you create your listener:

```
final TextView text = ...
```

Comment: When trying your first method:
`The constructor TextView(new View.OnTouchListener(){}) is undefined FullscreenActivity.java`

`debugText = new TextView(this);`

Comment: Doesn't sound like you wrote what I wrote/intended. init the TextView outside the Listener not in it.

Comment: Fixed: I had to use getApplicationContext() instead of this as the argument for the context.

Comment: I understand what you meant now: I initialized the TextView in onCreate instead.